# How to check if string contains particular characters

Tags: java, android

```
str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())
```

works except it returns true for "11 contains 1" but I want it to search for 1 and not 11 or 213 or any occurrence of 1 but just 1 alone

Comment: What does "just 1 alone" means, exactly?

Comment: split by space or new line and check result array contains your particular characters?

Comment: Way too broad/unclear. Try researching https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your string and do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
   if (str[i] == 'your character')
   // your code ...
}
```

Comment: Very inefficient. Regexes will perform way better.

Comment: I agree with you ;) ! +1

Comment: How does that apply here.    if(liked.toLowerCase()contains(userid)){button1.setTextColor(c.get resources().getColor(R.color.color accent));}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "fsdhfh11sdfsjad";
        Pattern patternOne = Pattern.compile("(.)*(1)(.)*");
        Pattern patternOneOne = Pattern.compile("(.)*(11)(.)*");

        Matcher matchOne = patternOne.matcher(s);
        Matcher matchOneOne = patternOneOne.matcher(s);

        if(matchOne.find() && !matchOneOne.find()){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }

    }
}
```

You can test your String with regex like these. This works for me. I hope it could help you. :)

Greethings

Noixes